# StackExchange.Redis support for ZPOP?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to impliment `ZPOP` for my application using StackExchange.Redis.  According to the [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) in the WATCH section, `ZPOP` can be implemented with the following commands:

```
WATCH zset
element = ZRANGE zset 0 0
MULTI
ZREM zset element
EXEC
```

In StackExchange Redis, this would look something like:

```
var connection = GetMultiplexer();
var db = connection.GetDatabase();
var trans = db.CreateTransaction();

var elements = await trans.SortedSetRangeByScoreAsync(key, 0, 0);  // THIS WILL BLOCK INDEFINITELY
var element = elemenets.FirstOrDefault();
trans.SortedSetRemoveAsync(key, element);
await trans.ExecuteAsync();
```

My question is, how can you get and use results from within a transaction?  How can I implement `ZPOP`?

Comment: Are you looking for a blocking ZPOP?

Comment: Yes, I need a blocking ZPOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a LUA script for that.
Redis guarantees that lua scripts are transactional, because when an eval script is running, nothing else can run concurrently. So you can use [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/eval).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/droot/1033867) is an example of how can you do the ZPOP with a LUA script:

```
local val = redis.call('zrange', KEYS[1], 0, 0)
if val then redis.call('zremrangebyrank', KEYS[1], 0, 0) end
return val
```

Also a [ZREVPOP](https://gist.github.com/droot/1033870) is provided.

With StackExchange.Redis you can load and execute LUA scripts with `IServer.ScriptLoad` and `IDatabase.ScriptEvaluate`.

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Transactions.md

Note this is not blocking. and will not be a good idea to have blocking code within the `ConnectionMultiplexer`.

From Stackexchange.Redis [documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/PipelinesMultiplexers.md#multiplexing):

> ...the only redis features that StackExchange.Redis does not offer (and
>   will not ever offer) are the "blocking pops" (BLPOP, BRPOP and
>   BRPOPLPUSH) - because this would allow a single caller to stall the
>   entire multiplexer

Comment: I'll take a look at this.  I might just use a non sorted list however... Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I'll just stick with SPOP :)  Thanks for the help!